# How to split an enum into two parts in different crates?

Tags: rust

Here's where I'm starting from:

```
#[derive(PartialEq)]
enum ControlItem {
    A {
        name: &'static str,
    },
    B {
        name: &'static str,
    },
}

struct Control {
    items: Vec<(ControlItem, bool)>,
}

impl Control {
    pub fn set(&mut self, item: ControlItem, is_ok: bool) {
        match self.items.iter().position(|ref x| (**x).0 == item) {
            Some(idx) => {
                self.items[idx].1 = is_ok;
            }
            None => {
                self.items.push((item, is_ok));
            }
        }
    }

    pub fn get(&self, item: ControlItem) -> bool {
        match self.items.iter().position(|ref x| (**x).0 == item) {
            Some(idx) => return self.items[idx].1,
            None => return false,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut ctrl = Control { items: vec![] };
    ctrl.set(ControlItem::A { name: "a" }, true);
    assert_eq!(ctrl.get(ControlItem::A { name: "a" }), true);
    ctrl.set(ControlItem::B { name: "b" }, false);
    assert_eq!(ctrl.get(ControlItem::B { name: "b" }), false);
}
```

I have a `Control` type that should save the state of some predefined items and report it back to user.

I have a virtual table in my mind, like this:

```
|Name in program | Name for user             |
|item_1          | Item one bla-bla          |
|item_2          | Item two bla-bla          |
|item_3          | Item three another-bla-bla|
```

1. I want `Control` to have `get` / `set` methods that accept only things with names `item_1`, `item_2`, `item_3`.
2. I want to hold this virtual table in two crates: "main" and "platform". Most of the implementation of `Control` should be in the main crate, and definitions of the items (like `item_3`) should go into the platform crate.  I want to register `item_3` at compile time.

Any ideas on how achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should use a trait, not an enum. You could define a trait and implement it like this:

```
pub trait ControlItem {
    fn name(&self) -> &str;
}

struct A(&'static str);

impl ControlItem for A {
    fn name(&self) -> &str {
        self.0
    }
}

// ... similar struct and impl blocks for other items
```

Then these structs can be moved into separate crates.

You'd need to change `Control` to store a `Vec<(Box<ControlItem>, bool)>`, and either change `get` and `set` to take a `Box<ControlItem>`, or to be generic over `T: ControlItem`.

Read about [traits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/traits.html) and [trait objects](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/trait-objects.html) for more.

Comment: The problem with `ControlItem`, that I want have predefined set of `ControlItem` and not allow any other in `set` and `get`, without this restriction I can just use `String` instead of `ControlItem`.

Comment: But you said before you wanted to open it up so that different `ControlItem`s  could be in different crates.

Comment: Yes, it should be in different crates, but it should be `open up` only at compile time. Set of possible `ControlItem` should be fixed at compile time, and `set` and `get` should accept only them.