# How can I create an enum-like type whose variants are defined by multiple crates?

Tags: enums, rust

I'm working on a system that generates and processes I/O events. I would like to do this by creating "filters" that handle the events they understand and forward all others to a fallback filter. For example, a console output crate could define `PrintString` and `SetColor` events and expose a `ConsoleOutputFilter`:

```
// pseudo-Rust for an event filter
impl<Fallback: EventFilter> EventFilter for ConsoleOutputFilter<Fallback> {
    fn handle(evt: Event) {
        match evt {
            PrintString(str) => print!("{}", str),
            SetColor(r, g, b) => { /* somehow change the text color */ },
            _ => Fallback::handle(evt)
        }
    }
}
```

If `ConsoleOutputFilter` receives any other kind of event (say, an `AlertBox` event defined by a GUI crate), it would just ignore it and pass it to the next event filter in the chain.

This seems like a reasonable design, but I'm unsure how to define the `Event` type. Using an enum seemed like a reasonable choice at first, but that would mean that I'd have to define all possible events in a single crate instead of splitting them into multiple packages.

[An answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39003567/3308630) suggested using trait objects, but I'm not sure how I would handle the fact that each event type could have a different associated data type. I'd also like to be able to serialize/deserialize events (e.g. to send them over the network), and that doesn't seem to be possible with trait objects.

In Rust, is there a way to create a type that behaves sort of like an enum with associated data, but whose variants can be defined in multiple crates?

Comment: I think the best way is to use trait. Define the contracts (with callbacks, eg) and then no matter what is the data implementing the trait.

Comment: `Box<Any>` will solve the dispatching part easily, but serialization is definitely trickier. I am not sure serde covers the requirements; you may need to invest into your own serialization system (and have a registry of deserialization functions to dispatch to based on the "tag" of the concrete type).